# Taylor Polynomial Notation

Tags: notation, taylor-expansion

$$D^If(0,0,0)$$

I am working with taylor polynomials and came across this notation, where $I$ is a point, $f$ is a function, and $D$ is (i think), the taylor polynomial of that function. Does this just represent that point I plugged into the polynomial D for the function f centered at the origin?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't rather a derivative, if $I=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$, then $D^I=\frac{\partial^{n_1+n_2+n_3}}{\partial x_1^{n_1}\partial x_2^{n_2}\partial x_2^{n_3}}$ or maybe $\frac{\partial^{n_1+n_2+n_3}}{(n_1+n_2+n_3)\partial x_1^{n_1}\partial x_2^{n_2}\partial x_2^{n_3}}$. If it is indeed a Taylor polynomial, perhaps it means the Taylor polynomial with the degree of $x_i$ being $\leq n_i$, for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of embedded images.

Comment: @user85667 that seems right, the previous part of the question was about taylor polynomials, so I assumed this might be too but its probably a derivative. How would I go about figuring out which of two derivatives you suggested is correct? Also do you happen to know what this notation is called? Thanks

Comment: When you say "[I] came across this notation," you should explain precisely *where* you encountered the notation.  Is it from a book?  what book?  a website?  can you give us a link?  Is this notation defined anywhere in the source you are reading from?

Comment: @figbar In the second option that I wrote it should be there factorial $(n_1+n_2+n_3)!$. In Taylor theorem there are factorials under the derivatives. If you see terms like $\frac{D^{I}f(0,0,0)}{I!}x^I$ then it must be the first option. If you see terms like $D^{I}f(0,0,0)x^I$, then the put the factorials inside the $D$.